# Recursive function to go through list of references to indices in same list

Tags: python, recursion

I have this list:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6, 7], [8], [9], [10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16], [15, 16], [15, 16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [20], [21], [], [], [], [], []]
```

It could be described as a list of references to other items in the same list, like this:

```
0 --> 1 2 3 4
1 --> 5
2 --> 6 7
3 --> 8
4 --> 9
5 --> 10 11
6 --> 12 13 14
7 --> 15 16
8 --> 15 16
9 --> 15 16
10 --> 17
11 --> 18
12 --> 19
13 --> 20
14 --> 21
15 --> 20
16 --> 21
17 --> None
18 --> None
19 --> None
20 --> None
21 --> None
```

So, from index 0 one can move to either 1, 2, 3 or 4. From 1 you can go to 5, and from 5 you can go to 10 etc. until you can't go any further (like when you reach index 17).

I'm trying to make a function that would return this when fed the above list:

```
[0,1,5,10,17]
[0,1,5,11,18]
[0,2,6,12,19]
[0,2,6,13,20]
[0,2,6,14,21]
[0,2,7,15,20]
[0,2,7,16,21]
[0,3,8,15,20]
[0,3,8,16,21]
[0,4,9,15,20]
[0,4,9,16,21]
```

Unfortunately, I just can't come up a solution.

I understand that this probably calls for a recursive function, but I'm getting so confused by it. Without actually knowing what I did, I managed to come up with this function:

```
def recurse_into(A,i):
    B = [i]
    for j in tree[i]:
        B += recurse_into(A,j)
    return B
```

It returns this:

```
[0, 1, 5, 10, 17, 11, 18, 2, 6, 12, 19, 13, 20, 14, 21, 7, 15, 20, 16, 21, 3, 8, 15, 20, 16, 21, 4, 9, 15, 20, 16, 21]
```

From that I probably could come up with something that generates the wanted results, but I wonder how I could get the result I want directly from the recursive function.

I would very much appreciate some pointers or tips on how to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: What you have here is called a graph. In fact, the graph you have is a special kind called a tree. You are writing a function to find all paths from the root of the tree to any leaf. Maybe this terminology will help you find some more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Wow, thanks! So it's called a graph, huh? Interesting. Thanks for giving me a search query I can use!

Comment: With that said, let's think about what `recurse_into()` should return? You currently return a 1D list, but your description shows that you need to return a 2D list. Let's assume that `recurse_into()` works correctly when you call `recurse_into(A, j)` and returns a 2D list. This is a list of all the paths from node `j` to leafs. How do you build the list of paths from node `i` to the leafs from the list that `recurse_into(A, j)` returns?

Comment: Yes, looking at it it's pretty obvious it won't return a 2D list like I want, since I'm just extending the list B. I somehow need to stop when I reach an empty list (or leaf as I'm slowly starting to realize it might be called) and start with a new list. But I just can't grasp how to do that!

Comment: Thinking about the base case at a leaf node is good. Your current for loop might take care of it if `tree[i]` is an empty list.  The problem is that `B` isn't a 2D array. How can you modify it it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my implementation of what I understood from my requirements

```
def dfs(graph, u, curr,res):
    c = curr+ [u]
    if(len(graph[u]) == 0):
        res.append(c)
    for v in graph[u]:
        dfs(graph, v, c, res)
        
    
    
graph = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6, 7], [8], [9], [10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16], [15, 16], [15, 16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [20], [21], [], [], [], [], []]

u = 0
res = []
dfs(graph, u, [],res)

print(res)
```

So I'm doing a DFS here.

Answer (score 1):

```
tree = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6, 7], [8], [9], [10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16], [15, 16], [15, 16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [20], [21], [], [], [], [], []]

def recourse_into(i):
    R=[]
    if len(tree[i]) ==0 :
            return [[i]]
    for h in  tree[i]:
        t=recourse_into(h)
        for j in t :
            R.append([i]+j)
    return R


print(recourse_into(0))
```